# Trace works differently with different right-hand-side rules—bug?

Tags: bugs, debugging

**Bug introduced in 2.1 or earlier and persisting through 13.2**

*UPDATE: Wolfram Support has confirmed that this is a bug.*

---

I noticed that `Trace` does the following strange thing (v 13.0.0.0):

```
Trace[a*a*2, x_ :> test]
(* Out: {test, test} *)

Trace[a*a*2, x_ :> x]
(* Out: {HoldForm[2*a^2], HoldForm[2*a^2], HoldForm[2*a^2]} *)
```

The first output has two elements, while the second has three. But shouldn't `x_` be matched the same number of times in each?

What might be going on? Is this a bug?

---

*Note: the original example used the rule `x : Times[___] :> ...`. As MichaelE2 pointed out, this evaluates to `x___ :> ...`; in this case, all matched expressions are necessarily exactly one expression long, and so `x_` reproduces the same behavior. So, I've modified the example to make it more minimal while still retaining the original character. The responses to this post were made before this edit, and thus may instead use `x : Times[___] :> ...`*

---

Some more facts:

(maybe this should be moved to the community wiki? will re-evaluate in the morning...)

An even more minimal example: `Trace[a*a, x_ :> x]` returns `{a^2, a^2}`; `Trace[a*a, x_ :> test]` returns `{}`.

A discrepancy only seems to occur when either:

- the evaluation involves downvalues producing an expression which 1) is composite in some way 2) involves "nontrivial" replacement/substitution of patterns
- the evaluation involves rearranging due to an attribute, like `Orderless` or `Flat`.

```
(* easily test for discrepancies—True indicates a discrepancy *)
SetAttributes[DiscrepancyQ, HoldFirst]

DiscrepancyQ[expr_] := 
 Module[{test}, 
  Trace[expr, x_ :> test] =!= (Trace[expr, x_ :> x] /. HoldForm[_] -> test)]

(* Note: subvalues behave like downvalues in all respects that
   I've tested, but I didn't want to write them all out. *)

(* Discrepancies: *)

(* Orderless: *)
Block[{f},
 SetAttributes[f, Orderless];
 DiscrepancyQ[f[2,1]]
]

(* Flat: *)
Block[{f},
 SetAttributes[f, Flat];
 DiscrepancyQ[f[1, f[2]]]
]

(* Downvalues producing "composite" expressions
   and involving replacement are bad, and yield True: *)
Block[{f},
 f[a_] := {a};
 DiscrepancyQ[f[1]]
]

Block[{f},
 f[a_] := a[1];
 DiscrepancyQ[f[1]]
]

Block[{f, h},
 f[a_] := h[a];
 DiscrepancyQ[f[1]]
]

Block[{f},
 f[a_] := (a;1);
 DiscrepancyQ[f[1]]
]


(* No discrepancies: *)

(* Downvalues with no pattern replacement are fine: *)
Block[{f},
 f[a_] := 1;
 DiscrepancyQ[f[1]]
]

(* Downvalues of these particular "purely extractive" forms are fine: *)
Block[{f},
 f[a_] := a;
 DiscrepancyQ[f[1]]
]

Block[{f},
 f[a_, b_] := a; (* or b *)
 DiscrepancyQ[f[1, 2]]
]

(* Upvalues are fine: *)
Block[{a},
 a /: f_[a] := {f, a};
 DiscrepancyQ[f[1]]
]

(* Ownvalues are fine: *)
Block[{f},
 f := {Hold[f], 1};
 DiscrepancyQ[f[1]]
]
```

Comment: Looks like a bug indeed. It is worth reporting to the support. There must be three matches: `Trace[a*a*2]` and `Trace[a*a*2, x : Times[___] :> HoldForm@x]` both return {a a 2, 2 a a, 2 a^2}.

Comment: The described behavior is the same with versions 5.2 and 8.0.4.

Comment: Ok, I've reported it to support (and shared with them the link to this post, so they can see MichaelE2's very interesting observation below as well!). We'll see what they say!

Comment: Another observation: `TracePrint[a*a*2]` shows just two evaluations of `Times[..]`.  The `Orderless` sorting and evaluation `2 a a` to `2 a^2` is one evaluation; then `2 a^2` is evaluated and doesn't change, so evaluation halts. -- Yet another observation: `x : Times[___]` evaluates to `x___` because `Times` has the attribute `OneIdentity`. It does not really make a difference, but we should have used `x : HoldPattern[Times[___]]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 nice catch! I've edited it to reflect that—but explained the edit in a note, so that the responses which use `Times[___]` are hopefully still appropriately contextualized.

Comment: Confirmed in _v2.1_: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqa0a.png (And `Trace` is introduced in _v2_. )

Answer (score 8):

CW because it's too long a comment.

A small difference that is not even part of the traced evaluation causes the same behavior as in the OP:

```
nn = 0;
test := ++nn;  (* <-- the only difference *)
Trace[a*a*2, x : Times[___] :> test]

(*  {1,2,3}  *)

nn = 0;
test := nn;    (* <-- the only difference *)
Trace[a*a*2, x : Times[___] :> test]

(*  {0, 0}  *)
```

The following shows that it matches three times but only two `test` show up in the output.

```
ClearAll[test];
nn = 0;
Trace[a*a*2, x : Times[___] /; (nn++; True) :> test]
nn

(*
  {test, test}

  3
*)
```

I was trying to figure out which `test` was dropped in the output, first, second, or third.  I couldn't.

I don't completely understand this bullet point from the docs for `Trace`:

> - In general, `form` in `Trace[expr,form]` is compared both with each complete expression that is evaluated and with the tag associated with any transformation rule used in the evaluation.

The last half that mentions "transformation rule" would seem to apply to the OP's examples, but I don't know how.

Comment: Another small difference (parenthesis versus braces): `Trace[a*a*2, x : Times[___] :> (nn; test)]` (two times), versus `Trace[a*a*2, x : Times[___] :> {nn; test}]` (three times). No `nn` and each gives just two `test` or `{test}` respectively.

Answer (score 6):

The following shows that the pattern indeed matches and the transformation is applied three times, but one of the results is removed on a postprocessing step inside of `Trace`:

```
Reap[Trace[a*a*2, x : HoldPattern[Times[___]] :> (Sow[HoldForm@x]; e)]]
```

> ```
> {{HoldForm[e], HoldForm[e]}, {{HoldForm[a*a*2], HoldForm[2*a*a], HoldForm[2*a^2]}}}
> ```

I think that this discrepancy already proves that it is a bug.

The *parenthesis versus braces* difference shown by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) in the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263040/trace-works-differently-with-different-right-hand-side-rules-bug/263046#comment655070_263045) sheds some light on the mechanism used for output filtering inside of `Trace`:

```
Trace[a*a*2, x : HoldPattern[Times[___]] :> {out}]
Trace[a*a*2, x : HoldPattern[Times[___]] :> {Null; out}]
Trace[a*a*2, x : HoldPattern[Times[___]] -> {Null; out}]
Trace[a*a*2, x : HoldPattern[Times[___]] :> Sequence @@ {out}]
```

> ```
> {HoldForm[{out}], HoldForm[{out}]}
> ```

> ```
> {HoldForm[{out}], HoldForm[{out}], HoldForm[{out}]}
> ```

> ```
> {HoldForm[{out}], HoldForm[{out}], HoldForm[{out}]}
> ```

> ```
> {HoldForm[out], HoldForm[out], HoldForm[out]}
> ```

Apparently, the filtering depends on whether the final expression has changed upon evaluation, or not.

I reproduce this behavior with *Mathematica* versions 13.0.0, 8.0.4 and 5.2 on Windows 10 x64.